Drupal webform element for HTML5 input type datetime-local
I would like to include a field in a Drupal 10 Webform that uses the HTML5 input type "datetime-local".  The available webform element for date and time appears to split the date and time field into two separate inputs in the form.  I know I can use the "datetime-local" type for the date input, but I can't disable the time input so the form has one date/time input and another time input.  It is possible to disable the date input but not the time input, the opposite functionality would let me achieve my goal.
Put simply, I would like to a single input with the type "datetime-local".

you can just alter the form and unset the time field or set default value and hide it from user using css / js.
